# Cumulocity API call with Device Group or Device Type or multiple source

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to call the event/alert API but filter the results by Device Type or Device Group, or as a last resort with multiple sources. Is there a way to make a sigle call to the API to achieve this result? At the moment I use /inventory/managedObjects with a device type first to get a list of devices, and then loop through the results and make a call to events/alarms for every device but this doesn't seem like a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to query event and alarm APIs for a collection of source IDs. You can only query by a single ID.

If you are completly unhappy with calling for every device in the group there are two workarouns that come to my mind:

You query all and filter on the client (the more groups you have the worse this method will be).

You can create an event processing rule that adds an additional fragment to every created alarm and event based on the device group (incoming alarm -> check source -> check parents of the source (there is a function findAllManagedObjectParent). E.g. you add:

"myDeviceGroupName": {}

to all alarms and events.
Afterwards you can query the APIs not by source but by fragmentType.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be sure, how would I use fragmentType in this API call for example to specify a device group post-iot.lu/measurement/measurements?source=26932 ?

Comment: You would query /measurement/measurements?fragmentType=myDeviceGroupName

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this when I have a chance.